# Flutter 2.0 following dependencies don't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

```
- package:bloc
- package:flutter_bloc
- package:provider
```

Answer (score 0):

flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

Comment: And if you're running Visual Studio Code, watch my video on how to enable that for a project with VSC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nTEgyNvN2A